# Flask 'render_template' after client POST request

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

So, I'm working on a small web application that has a small canvas, the user is supposed to draw something and then I want to do some python with the image from that canvas. Like this:

[image]

This is working fine. When I press "Click me!", I call a JS function that POST the image to my Flask server. And this is also working, the thing is that after I receive the image, I want to render a new page to show some results, but this page is not rendering at all.

Now, I'm completely new to Javascript, barely know anything, basically every JS I'm using is copy pasted from the internet, so I'm assuming I must be missing something very simple, I just don't know what.

Here is the server code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import re
from io import BytesIO
import base64 
from PIL import Image

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
   return render_template('drawing.html')

@app.route("/hook", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def hook():
   image_data = re.sub('^data:image/.+;base64,', '', request.form['imageBase64'])
   im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(image_data)))
   im.show()
   return render_template('results.html')
```

The first route just opens the canvas, the second is executed after the client's request, which has this function:

```
function surprise() {
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/hook",
    data:{
      imageBase64: dataURL
    }
  }).done(function() {
    console.log('sent');
  });}
```

Apparently, this is working. I have the line:

```
im.show()
```

Just so I can see the image and I get exactly the drawing from the canvas, which I'm now supposed to work on:

[image]

but the results page is not rendered afterwards, nothing happens. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning the page to view in response to the call that posts the image. Instead, you should return a response (for example in a json format) containing the information regarding the result of the call just made (i.e. the post of the image) and consequently, on the client side, you must redirect the user to the appropriate page .

To understand why it is not working, print the content of the response returned from the call made

```
var response = '';
$.ajax({ type: "POST",   
         url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/hook",   
         data:{
             imageBase64: dataURL
         },
         success : function(text)
         {
             response = text;
         }
});

alert(response);
```

Comment: I get now what the problem is, but I'm still not sure how to do what I want. The point of render_template is that I can pass variables to the new rendered html, right? Let's say the result of some calculations on the image gives a result 3.45, I can pass it as a parameter render_template('results.html, result = result) and show it on the next screen. How do I do that from the client side? I guess I can return 'result' in the response json, but how do I pass it along to my results page from there?

Comment: To use render_template() the browser should get the response and display it. That happens when you have a html form and a submit button, you navigate to the next page, and that page is the result returned by render_template. In your case, you was using ajax, and in that case your browser do not navigate to the new page, just get the data